# Android NDK strange crash

Tags: android, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I'm having a bad issue with Android NDK. My app crashes with error 11 but the problem is that the stack dump makes no sense.

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/p4noterfub/p4noterf:4.1.2/JZO54K/N8000UBCML2:user/release-keys'
pid: 27557, tid: 27557, name: com.nirai.app  >>> com.nirai.app <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 5d2b601c
Stack frame #00  pc 000046d2  /system/bin/linker
Stack frame #01  pc 00005c3b  /system/bin/linker
Stack frame #02  pc 0004f90d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
Stack frame #03  pc 0001df30  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
Stack frame #04  pc 0004d183  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
Stack frame #05  pc 00027360  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #06  pc 0002bc68  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
Stack frame #07  pc 0005fbb7  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
Stack frame #08  pc 00067165  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #09  pc 00027360  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #10  pc 0002bc68  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
Stack frame #11  pc 0005f8f1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
Stack frame #12  pc 00049773  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #13  pc 0004c169  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
Stack frame #14  pc 0004d2cb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+390)
Stack frame #15  pc 00000dcf  /system/bin/app_process
Crash dump is completed
```

There's no reference to my lib (`libtest.so`) so I'm lost now!

Extra info:

```
NDK r8d
API 9
Testing on real unrooted device (emulator hangs with no crash)
```

Comment: was this working before, is something changed. does it happen only on some devices.

Comment: This never worked, first build and only test on my device (this crash) and emulator (app hangs)

Comment: I suggest to start with the HelloJni example (somewhere in the JDK) and continue with adding your code to it.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to happen at `System.load` - your
`NDK r8d` is really old (~2012) , lot of [bugs were fixed since then, strongly suggest you update](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Revisions) to latest NDK version r10b and try rebuilding your app with new toolchain.